# Why do I get a segmentation error in my Stream Editor program for larger input sizes?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I debugged the code below and I noticed my `editFileToStdIn`throws the segmentation error. What is the best way to solve this problem? You can test the code in your terminal by compiling with gcc and running like so `./svi command.txt < example.txt`. My code works for smaller inputs but gives a segmentation error for larger input sizes like these: [CommandFile](https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/wuchtys/CSC322-20S/Assessment/CommandFile1) and [ExampleFile](https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/wuchtys/CSC322-20S/Assessment/InputFile1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 100
typedef char String[256];

//SVI Data Structures
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
typedef enum {none,text,range} lineRangeSpec; //Range specification

// Union Structure for range specification
typedef union { 
    int none;
    String text;
    int range[2];
} lineRangeUnion;

//Edit Operators
typedef struct {
    lineRangeSpec specType;
    lineRangeUnion specifier;
    char editOperation; //will be one of {A,I,O,d,s}
    /*A - Appends the <text> at the end of the line
      I - Inserts the <text> at the start of the line.
      O - Inserts the <text> on a new line before the current line
      d - Deletes the line from the file.
      s - Replaces the first occurence of <old text>, in the line, with <new text>
  */
    String data; //Stores all text after edit operators have been taken
} EditOperator;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------//

//Read and store edit commands from file
//Read a line from standard input
bool isEditPossible(EditOperator edit, String currentLine, int lineNumber);
void editFile (EditOperator edit, String line);
int readEditFile (FILE * commands, EditOperator inputs[]);

//Synthesize Text based on Operation Specified
EditOperator editEverywhere (String command);
EditOperator editLineRange(String command);
EditOperator editText (String command);
EditOperator transformStruct(String input);
void swapDelimiters (String data, String former, String latter);
void swapText (EditOperator edit, String line);

//Output the edited line (unless it has been deleted)
void editFileToStdIn (EditOperator edits[], int length);

//Driver Code
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE * commands;
    int length;
    EditOperator values[ARRAY_SIZE];

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Error! Include a file name. e.g., `./svi a.txt >  b.txt `\n");
        return -1;
    } else if ((commands = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened. Program has ended.\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        length = readEditFile(commands, values);
        editFileToStdIn(values, length);
        return 0;
    }
}

void editFile (EditOperator val, String line){
  String text;
  int length;
  switch(val.editOperation){
    case 'A':
            strcpy(text, line);
            length = strlen(text) - 1;
            if (text[length] == '\n') {
                text[length] = '\0';
            }
            strcat(text, val.data);
            strcpy(line, text);
            break;
        case 'd':
            line[0] = '\0';
            break;
        case 'I':
            strcpy(text, val.data);
            length = strlen(text) - 1;
            if (text[length] == '\n') {
                text[length] = '\0';
            }
            strcat(text, line);
            strcpy(line, text);
            break;
        case 'O':
            printf("%s", val.data);
            break;
        case 's':
            swapText(val, line);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Irregularly edited input. Program terminated \n");
            exit(-1);
            break;
  }
}

void editFileToStdIn (EditOperator edits[], int length){
  String input;
    int currentLine = 0, i;
    while (fgets(input, 256, stdin)) {
        currentLine += 1;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (isEditPossible(edits[i], input, currentLine)) {
                editFile(edits[i], input);
                // if the edit says to delete this line, immediately break
                // so that other operations cannot be applied 
                if (edits[i].editOperation == 'd') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s", input);
}
}

void swapDelimiters (String data, String former, String latter){
  String value;
    char * delimiter = "/";
    char * token;
    strcpy(value, data);
    token = strtok(value, delimiter);
    strcpy(former, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    strcpy(latter, token);
}

bool isEditPossible(EditOperator edit, String currentLine, int lineNumber){
   if (edit.specType == range) {
        return edit.specifier.range[0] <= lineNumber && lineNumber <= edit.specifier.range[1];
    } else if (edit.specType == text) {
        return strstr(currentLine, edit.specifier.text) != NULL;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

int readEditFile (FILE * commands, EditOperator inputs[]){
  String line;
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < 100 && fgets(line, 256, commands) != NULL) {
        inputs[i] = transformStruct(line);
        i += 1;
    }
    // close the file since it is no longer needed
    if (fclose(commands) == EOF) {
        perror("Unable to close file. Exiting program.");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        return i;
}
}

EditOperator editLineRange(String command){
   EditOperator s;
    String copy;
    char * delimiters = ",/";
    char * delimiter = "/";
    char * token;

    s.specType = range;
    strcpy(copy, command);
    token = strtok(copy, delimiters);
    s.specifier.range[0] = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    s.specifier.range[1] = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    s.editOperation = token[0];
    strcpy(s.data, token + 1);
    return s;
}

EditOperator editText (String command) {
    EditOperator s;
    String copy;
    char * delimiter = "/";
    char * token;

    s.specType = text;
    strcpy(copy, command);

    // split string at first instance of '/'
    token = strtok(copy, delimiter);
    // and copy this into `Edit.rule.text`
    strcpy(s.specifier.text, token);

    // grab everything after the first slash to the null-terminator character
    token = strtok(NULL, "\0");
    // the first character is the edit type
    s.editOperation = token[0];
    // everything else is `Edit.data`
    strcpy(s.data, token + 1);

    return s;
}

EditOperator makeEverywhereEdit (String command) {
    EditOperator s;

    s.specType = none;
    s.specifier.none = true;
    strcpy(s.data, command + 1);
    s.editOperation = command[0];

    return s;
}

EditOperator editEverywhere (String command){
  EditOperator val;
  val.specType = none;
  val.specifier.none = true;
  strcpy(val.data, command + 1);
  val.editOperation = command[0];
  return val;
}

void swapText (EditOperator edit, String line) {
    String copy, replace, replaceWith;
    char * token;
    int i, delta, lengthOfReplace, lineLength;

    swapDelimiters(edit.data, replace, replaceWith);

    lengthOfReplace = strlen(replace);

    // in case there's garbage in `copy`
    strcpy(copy, "");

    // while line contains the text to be replaced
    while ((token = strstr(line, replace)) != NULL) {
        // let `delta` be the number of characters between the beginning of `line`
        // and the character at which `replace` was found in `line`
        delta = token - line;
        lineLength = strlen(line);

        // copy the `delta` characters of line before `replace` to `copy`
        strncat(copy, line, delta);
        // append `replaceWith` to `copy`
        strcat(copy, replaceWith);

        // shift the entire array forward, from the first character after the end of `replace`
        for (i = 0; i < lineLength - delta - lengthOfReplace + 1; i++) {
            line[i] = line[i + delta + lengthOfReplace];
        }
    }
    // while loop terminates when `replace` is no longer in `line`;
    // copy remaining character of `line` after last occurrence of `replace` to copy
    strcat(copy, line);
    // move `copy` to `line` (since it was passed by reference)
    strcpy(line, copy);
}

EditOperator transformStruct(String input){
    if ('0' <= input[0] && input[0] <= '9') {
        return editLineRange(input);
    } else if (input[0] == '/') {
        return editText(input);
    } else {
      return editEverywhere(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried catching the crash in a debugger? When and where in your code does it say the crash happen? What are the values of all involved variables at that time and place?

Comment: Perhaps - because type `String` is 256 characters, and you use that as a target for concatenations. Best to check the resultant lengths before doing them.

Comment: `assert(length < ARRAY_SIZE)`

Comment: Another thing, is you never check the result of `strtok` before dereferencing it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I noticed the programming crashes about halfway through the input files I referenced. You can test it out on my repl.it (https://repl.it/@isaacattuah/svi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to start using some flags when compiling.
If you enable the warnings as errors gcc won't let you compile without solving them.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c file_name.c
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o program file_name.o
$ ./program
```

This will show you your errors and also avoid compiling until you solved them.

Also you should try a debugger:

Maybe you may want use and investigate [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) in future when you have segmentation faults.
Just add the flag -g in the compilation command.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g -c file_name.c
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g -o program file_name.o
$ gdb ./program
```

Once you're in type "run" and you can see exactly where the segmentation fault is.

If you try this and get some information about the error please let me know what it says so I can try to help you more.

Hope it helps!